# Why does the state reset in functional react component when changing between pages using `react-router`

Tags: reactjs, react-router, use-state

Why does the state reset in react component when changing between pages using `react-router`?

---

As I understand it, you should be able to switch between routes (components) using `react-router` as long as you use the 'react' way of changing, ie. `<Link to="/otherRoute" />`. This is not the case for me and I do not see why. Here is the code:

**App.js**

```
import RoutesComp from "./RoutesComp";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>
        <Link to="/state">State</Link>
      </p>
      <p>
        <Link to="/dummy">dummy</Link>
      </p>
      <RoutesComp />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**StateComp.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const StateComp = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setCounter((prev) => prev + 1)}>click to increment</button>
      <p>{counter}</p>{" "}
    </>
  );
};

export default StateComp
```

**RoutesComp.js**

```
import React from "react";

import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import StateComp from "./StateComp";
import Dummy from "./Dummy";

const RoutesComp = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/state" render={() => <StateComp />} />
        <Route path="/dummy" render={() => <Dummy />} />

// I also tried it the original way
        {/* <Route path="/state">
          <StateComp />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/dummy">
          <Dummy />
        </Route> */}
      </Switch>
    </>
  );
};

export default RoutesComp;
```

This produces the following:

[image]

When you click on the increment button, the count goes up, but when you go to the 'dummy' page and come back to the 'state' page, the counter is at 0 again.

From my research,
[react router difference between component and render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150567/react-router-difference-between-component-and-render) it looks like the state will be reset if you create routes using

```
<Route path="/state">
    <StateComp />
</Route>
<Route path="/dummy">
    <Dummy />
</Route>
```

However, it seems like the way to get the state to not be reset is to use `render={() => <Comp/>}`.
I tried that as well and that did not work.

Can anyone offer some insight as to what I'm doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:**
Dependencies/Versions

```
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
```

Comment: Hi, I've did a little digging around this topic. Looks like this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45930922/5281962 . In short, don't use `Switch` component and use the `children` prop for the `Route` component. Here's an example that I have implemented: https://codesandbox.io/s/persist-state-react-router-1t4bl

Comment: @Cherubim thanks for this guidance. This helps me out. Though, I am disappointed that there seems to be no built in way to do this with react-router. I guess one way is to lift the state up outside of the component that rerenders using redux or the context API.

Comment: @Cherubim Please feel free to put your comment as an answer and I will gladly select it as the best answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Switch` component only ever renders a single route, the earliest match wins. All the components whose routes do not get matched are unmounted.

To avoid this, you need to move you `Route` components outside of the `Switch` component and use the `children` property to render your component.

Here's an example that implements the above mentioned approach: [example codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/persist-state-react-router-1t4bl)

Some other workarounds include:

1. Lifting up your state using either `redux` or `useContext` API
2. use the url parameters to store the state(not suitable for complex components)

---

Helpful links:

1. [React-router: never unmount a component on a route once mounted, even if route change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45917133/5281962)
2. [How to persist state across react router transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32126853/5281962)